# Turn off output messages from bsub dispatch

Tags: unix, tcl

I am using a `bsub` LSF to run tests and using a progress bar to show how far along the tests are in the Unix terminal. Is there anyway to turn off the dispatch messages received from `bsub`. I am writing a tcl script and whenever the messages `<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>` and `<<Starting on server>>` appear it causes the progress bar to stop what its doing and creates a new one.

Is it at all possible to turn off these messages or atleast have a work around for the progress bar not to repeat itself?

Comment: Those messages go to stderr. Will your script still work if you redirect stderr, perhaps to /dev/null?

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue! I didn't think to redirect it using `2>&1` I was trying to figure out how to use `bsub -e`. Thank you :)